# На каком языке написана программа?

Tags: php

Нашел вот такую программу, которая должна вычислять пароль роутера из хэша. Вроде бы пароль шифруется xor'ом

```
$Password = "89929E87BECABDC8C6BC";

for($i=0;$i<strlen($Password);$i+=2){
    echo "&#".(255-hexdec($Password[$i].$Password[$i+1])).";";
}
```

Непонятно какой интерпретатор или компилятор использовать, чтобы запустить. Подскажите, на каком языке написана программулина и с чем ее можно запустить.

Comment: На английском. Угадал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это PHP.

Можно перевести на другой язык. Например, C#:

```
string password = "89929E87BECABDC8C6BC";

for (int i=0; i < password.Length; i += 2)
    Console.Write("&#" + (255-hexdec(password[i], password[i+1])) + ";";

int hexdec(char c1, char c2)
{
    string hexdigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    return hexdigits.IndexOf(c1) * 16 + hexdigits.IndexOf(c2);
}
```

То же на C++:

```
std::string password = "89929E87BECABDC8C6BC";

for (int i = 0; i < password.size(); i += 2)
    std::cout << "&#" << (255-hexdec(password[i], password[i+1])) << ";";

int hexdec(char c1, char c2)
{
    std::string hexdigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    return hexdigits.find(c1) * 16 + hexdigits.find(c2);
}
```

Если вы хотите увидеть сам пароль, замените вывод на такой:

```
std::cout << (char)(255-hexdec(password[i], password[i+1]));
```

Comment: ну какой же это может быть перл?

Comment: В Perl нету strlen? Тогда только PHP.

---
Проверил, и правда, спасибо! Обновил ответ.

Comment: дело не в том, если ли strlen, дело в том, что видим такое обращение `$Password[$i]`, а это значит, что Password - должен быть массивом. Но тогда при вызове strlen он должен был бы записываться как `@Password`, так как `$Password` это совсем другая переменная.

Comment: Народ, спасибо, но как мне его запусить под Линуксом? Никогда с php дела не имел!

Comment: создать текстовый файл, скопировать туда текст, в самое начало добавить `<?php`, в самый конец - `?>`. Запускать с консоли - php имя_файла.
А можно посмотреть - http://codepad.org/x2en3VUL

Comment: Спасибо. Это я уже вроде нашел до ответа, но получаю:

    php passwd.php
&#118;&#109;&#97;&#120;&#65;&#53;&#66;&#55;&#57;&#67;

а должен получить vmaxA5B79C

Оригинал программы и найденный пароль здесь - http://aum-saraswati.livejournal.com/4158.html

Где-то ошибка или надо еще ответ обработать?

Comment: самый простой способ перевести это назад в читаемый вид - вставить в поисковик (например гугл) и будет понятно:)

Comment: Все понял, спасибо - это ASCII коды в dec